# Lua pointers to merge 3 functions

Tags: lua

How can I create pointers so i can make 1 function instead of 3?
I have function that works like:

```
for a,b in pairs(places3) do
    char3.moveObject(b[1]) 
end
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

```
for i=1,3,1 do
    for a,b in pairs(places+i) do
        char+i.moveObject(b[1]) 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have something like the following:

```
local places1 = { some data }
local places2 = { some data }
local places3 = { some data }

local char1 = some table with a moveObject() function
local char2 = some table with a moveObject() function
local char3 = some table with a moveObject() function
```

Then I'd do like this:

```
-- create pairs of char and places
local char_place_pairs = {
    { char = char1, places = places1 },
    { char = char2, places = places2 },
    { char = char3, places = places3 },
}

-- iterate over the pairs and per pair call the moveObject function for each entry in places
for _,char_place_pair in pairs(char_place_pairs) do
    for a,b in pairs(char_place_pair.places) do
        char_place_pair.char.moveObject(b[1]) 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement three functions for three tables. Simply implement 1 function that takes a table and call it three times.

Something like:

```
function move(places, char)
  for _, place in pairs(places) do
    char.moveObject(place)
  end
end
```

then simply call

```
move(places1, char1)
move(places2, char2)
move(places3, char3)
```

or put all chars and places into tables

```
places = {places1, places2, places3}
chars = {char1, char2, char3}

for i, char in ipairs(chars) do
  move(places[i], char)
end
```

There are many many ways.